# how to rewrite joomla pagination to friendly url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, joomla, pagination

I want to rewrite pagination URLs `http://mydomain.com/category?start=15` to `http://mydomain.com/category/start/15`, but I don't know how to achieve this with .htaccess.

PS: those URls ( `http://mydomain.com/category?start=15`) are referenced in search engines so I need to add 301 redirect to my new URLs.
I want mention that I already enabled SEF mode in Jommla configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you want your URLs to look like `/start/15` you have to rewrite them from the pretty format to the internal, not otherwise.

I currently have no access to an Apache, but your expression should look something simliar to this:

```
RewriteRule ^category/start/([0-9]+)$ http://mydomain.com/category?start=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Then, it would be neccesary to tell Joomla how to generate the pretty URLs, this happens without the htaccess file, for example in a SEO plugin.

Finally, to output 301 messages, you will want to add "`Redirect`" commands to your .htaccess file. Redirect incoming `?start=15` URLs to the pretty format. Make sure that this does not happen after your Rewrite...

Comment: Think you, yes I do that, but the problem that I had is this "category" is not a physical link but just an alias to `index.php?option=mycomponent&view=myview&id=myid` so I use this link and the problem solved.

Comment: Now I want to make `301 redirect` so I add this code the haccess `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^start=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule  category category/start/%1 [R=301,L]` but it append me `?start=15` at the last of the new request and it become some thing like: `http:://mydomain.com/category/start/15/?start`. Do you have an idea how can I remove this?

Comment: Try to end your target path with a question mark, like category/start/%1? - this should strip the query string from the URL.